# I have an array that is being altered even though I have not specifically changed it

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am writing an AI to play Mancala and this is my method in which the AI's calculations are done by examining the outcomes of all 6 possible moves.  I use the array staticBoardState to restore boardState (which stores the information about all of the holes on the board) back to its original values after each examination of move outcomes, but staticBoardState seems to be changing in odd ways even though I believe that I do not change it.  I am a beginner amateur coder, so please ask questions if my code does not make sense.  This is my code:

```
public int getBotCalc(int boardState[]) {

    int[] staticBoardState = boardState;

    double[] movePoints = new double[6];
    int initialScore = boardState[6];
    int scorePoints;
    int freeTurnPoints;

    double bestMovePoints;
    int bestMove;

    for(int f = 0; f <= 5; f++) {

        boardState = staticBoardState;

        int botChoice = f;
        int botHole = boardState[botChoice];
        boardState[botChoice] = 0;

        for(int g = 0; g < botHole; g++) {

            botChoice++;
            if(botChoice>12) {
                botChoice = 0;
            }

            boardState[botChoice]++;
        }

        if(botChoice<=5&&boardState[botChoice]==1&&boardState[12-botChoice]>=1) {
            boardState[6] += boardState[12 - botChoice] + 1;

            boardState[botChoice] = 0;
            boardState[12 - botChoice] = 0;
        }

        scorePoints = boardState[6] - initialScore;
        if(botChoice==6) {
            freeTurnPoints = 1;
        } else {
            freeTurnPoints = 0;
        }

        movePoints[f] = scorePoints + (1.5 * freeTurnPoints);
    }

    bestMovePoints = movePoints[0];
    bestMove = 0;
    for(int f = 1; f <= 5; f++) {
        if(movePoints[f]>bestMovePoints) {
            bestMovePoints = movePoints[f];
            bestMove = f;
        }
    }

    boardState = staticBoardState;

    return bestMove;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both `staticBoardState` and `boardState` are references to the same object (the same array). The `=` operator doesn't create a copy of the array, it just sets the variable to reference that object. Changes to `boardState` will be reflected in the `staticBoardState` array and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're confusing value-type assignment with reference assignment. When you write

> `staticBoardState = boardState`

what happens is that `staticBoardState` simply holds a reference to the array in memory that `boardState` is also already referring to. Not they both refer to the same array in memory, which is why `staticBoardState` is apparently being modified through the use of `boardState`. What you need to do to fix this is allocate `staticBoardState` as a *new* array and explicitly copy its contents, for example using a `boardState.clone()`, and perform similar copying each time you want to restore your `boardState`.

Comment: `staticBoardState = boardState.clone()`

Comment: Thanks @shmosel, edit made. My C++ love shone through